# How to parse the http request from file using HttpMessageParser of apache

Tags: java, http, parsing

An Java application caputures the http requests and saves it in a file. I don't want to create myself a Parser to parse http request from file. Is there good http request parser api for that? I found a parser of apache http components, but I don't understand how do I use that.

Answer (score 0):

`SessionInputBuffer inputBuffer = new AbstractSessionInputBuffer() {
            {
                init(
                      new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.substring(beginIndex).replace(
                                "\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").getBytes()), 100,
                        new BasicHttpParams());
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isDataAvailable(int timeout) throws IOException {
                // Just need to override. Not actually called.
                return false;
            }
        };
        HttpMessageParser parser = new DefaultHttpResponseParser(
                inputBuffer, new BasicLineParser(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1)),
                new DefaultHttpResponseFactory(), new BasicHttpParams());`

```
        HttpResponse response = parser.parse();
```